# What are New York Window fees?

Tags: united-states, stocks, fees, brokerage, share-certificate

Someone told me that if the stock I want to buy/sell does not trade 100% electronically, my stock broker may need to handle physical share certificates. I was told that I could be charged a "New York Window" fee in connection with the handling of physical share certificates.

I may have misremembered some of details above, so my questions are:

- Is there really a fee called a "New York Window fee"?
- What exactly is this New York Window fee?
- Who charges this fee? Is it my broker? A clearing firm? The stock exchange?

I tried to look on Wikipedia and Investopedia, but there are no results. I also tried Google, but none of the results are relevant to stocks.

Comment: [This Investopedia page](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/stockcertificate.asp) mentions fees for physical certificates (although doesn't explicitly include "_New York Window fee_". [This Lightspeed fees page](https://www.lightspeed.com/pricing/other-fees/) _does_ mention a _New York Window Fee_ (of $34) but doesn't specify what it's for.

Comment: Related: https://www.dtcclearning.com/products-and-services/asset-services/custody/new-york-window.html and https://www.dtcc.com/clearing-services/equities-clearing-services/envelope-services